# Setter/Getter for custom object not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, properties

I have the following custom object:

```
@interface LoadDescription : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) float start, stop, startMagnitude, stopMagnitude;
@end
```

I have the object in one of my controllers as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LoadDescription *editingLoad;
```

But when I try to set/get the properties within the editingLoad property...

```
float tableValue = [textField.text floatValue]; 
NSLog(@"value in table is %f", tableValue);
self.editingLoad.startMagnitude = tableValue;
NSLog(@"Load magnitude is %i", (int)self.editingLoad.startMagnitude);
```

...and run iOS, the console output shows that while tableValue is whatever I input it as, self.editingLoad.startMagnitude is always 0.00000000, which makes me think that something's wrong with the setter/getter.

I am running ARC, if that's relevant.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check that self.editingLoad isn't nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the editingLoad object alloc'd and init'd prior to the property assignment?

If not that may be your problem, else if you are type cast int to float that is less than 1 i believe it will always be zero. I don't know what values you are expecting from the "tableValue"

What happens when the second log prints out a float/double "%f" ?

Comment: Yeah, you're dead-on with the alloc/init. Whoops. Thanks so much!

Comment: It should be _editingLoad = [[LoadDescription alloc] init] in the controller's init method, yes? Using self.editingLoad only worked if it was declared in the method including the variable assignment--effectively alloc/init'ing editingLoad multiple times, which seems strange.

Comment: No, I miss read... If you are initializing things in a ViewController the best place to do this is viewDidLoad method. The reason is because the standard init is not called for ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `@synthesize editingLoad;` so all getters and setters are generated for you.
and don't forget to alloc/init your custom object before assigning values:

```
self.editingLoad = [[LoadDescription alloc] init];
self.editingLoad.startMagnitude = tableValue;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You have one of the following issue:
1) You not define init method in your custom class.
2) You get nil value in "editingLoad" object.

Comment: The class inherits from NSObject, so shouldn't defining init be unnecessary? When would defining init in a custom class be necessary?